# PHP Function Gets Out Of Container Div

Tags: php

Basically I'm making a basic online store with PHP and I have made a file called `get_brands()` which simply get the brand names of products from db and goes like this:

```
    <?php 
function get_brands(){
    $get_brands = "select * from brands";
    $run_brands = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['con'],$get_brands);
    while($row_brands=mysqli_fetch_array($run_brands)){
        $brand_id = $row_brands['brand_id'];
        $brand_title = $row_brands['brand_title'];
        echo "
            <option value='$brand_id'>$brand_title</option>
        ";
    }
}
?>
```

Now I want to echo this inside my other page:

```
<div class='content-wrapper'>
        <section class='content-header'>
            <h1>
                Add New Products
                <small>onlinestore.danoup.com</small>
            </h1>
            <ol class='breadcrumb'>
                <li class='active'>insertproducts.php</li>
            </ol>
        </section>
        <?php 
        if(($dataSet->GetLevel()==1) || ($dataSet->GetLevel()==2)){ echo "
        <section class='content'>
            <div class='box box-default'>
                <div class='box-header with-border'>
                    <h3 class='box-title'>Overall Info</h3>

                    <div class='box-tools pull-right'>
                        <!-- <button type='button' class='btn btn-box-tool' data-widget='collapse'><i class='fa fa-minus'></i></button> 
                        <button type='button' class='btn btn-box-tool' data-widget='remove'><i class='fa fa-remove'></i></button> -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='box-body'>
                    <form action='' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
                        <div class='row'>
                            <div class='col-md-6'>
                                <div class='form-group'>
                                    <div class='form-group'>
                                        <label>Product Title:</label>
                                        <input type='text' name='product_title' class='form-control my-colorpicker1'>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class='form-group'>
                                    <label>Product Category:</label>
                                    <select class='form-control select2' name='product_cat' style='width: 100%;'>
                                        ".get_cats()."
                                        ?>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class='form-group'>
                                    <label>Product Brand:</label>
                                    <select class='form-control select2' name='product_brand' style='width: 100%;'>
                                        ".get_brands()."
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class='form-group'>
                                    <div class='form-group'>
                                        <label>Product Image 1:</label>
                                        <input type='file' name='product_img1' class='form-control my-colorpicker1'>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class='form-group'>
                                    <div class='form-group'>
                                        <label>Product Image 2:</label>
                                        <input type='file' name='product_img2' class='form-control my-colorpicker1'>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class='form-group'>
                                    <div class='form-group'>
                                        <label>Product Image 3:</label>
                                        <input type='file' name='product_img3' class='form-control my-colorpicker1'>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class='col-md-6'>
                                <div class='form-group'>
                                    <div class='form-group'>
                                        <label>Product Price:</label>
                                        <input type='text' name='product_price' class='form-control my-colorpicker1'>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class='form-group'>
                                    <div class='form-group'>
                                        <label>Product Keywords:</label>
                                        <input type='text' name='product_keywords' class='form-control my-colorpicker1'>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <input type='submit' name='insert_product' class='btn' value='Submit'>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class='row'>
                            <div class='col-md-12'>
                                <div class='box box-info'>
                                    <div class='box-header'>
                                        <h3 class='box-title'>Product Description:
                                            <small>Add new product to your onlinestore</small>
                                        </h3>
                                        <div class='pull-right box-tools'>
                                            <button type='button' class='btn btn-info btn-sm' data-widget='collapse' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Collapse'>
                                            <i class='fa fa-minus'></i></button>
                                            <button type='button' class='btn btn-info btn-sm' data-widget='remove' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Remove'>
                                            <i class='fa fa-times'></i></button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class='box-body pad'>
                                            <textarea name='product_desc' placeholder='Add description to your product' style='width: 100%; height: 200px; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; border: 1px solid #dddddd; padding: 10px;'></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class='box-footer'>
                    Visit <a href='https://zite.pouyavagefi.com/documentation/onlinestores.php'>Online Store</a> documentation and know more about this plugin.
                </div>
            </div>
        </section> ";
        }else{ 
            echo "
                <section class='content'>
                    <div class='alert alert-warning'>
                        <strong>Access Denied!</strong> You don\'t have permission to access this page.
                    </div> 
                </section> 
            ";
        }
        ?>
    </div>
```

And now the ONLY problem is that, it show the names outside the div and not inside the *select* tag which I have set ... (look at the print screen below):

[print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZWhE.png)

I don't know why this thing happen because I have set the code like this:

```
<div class='form-group'>
    <label>Product Brand:</label>
    <select class='form-control select2' name='product_brand style='width: 100%;'>
        ".get_brands()."
    </select>
</div>
```

So if you have any idea on this, please let me know, I really appreciate that!

Comment: I think it's time to start using normal page templating, instead of hardcoding your HTML in your PHP code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the `<option>` tags from your `get_brands` function, instead of echoing them directly. If you combine a function value into a string like this, then any `echo` calls in the function will happen first, since the string is evaluated by PHP before sending it to the browser.

A basic example is:

```
echo 1 . ' ' . two();
function two() {
  echo 2;
}
```

This will actually display `2 1`, since the function is run while building the string, and its `echo` statement runs first.

To get the code running correctly, we can change it to:

```
echo 1 . ' ' . two();
function two() {
  return 2;
}
```

This will correctly display `1 2`, since the function no longer calls `echo` directly.

For your example, you should build up a string of `<option>` tags in `get_brands`, and return it:

```
$return = '';

while($row_brands=mysqli_fetch_array($run_brands)){
    $brand_id = $row_brands['brand_id'];
    $brand_title = $row_brands['brand_title'];
    $return .= "
        <option value='$brand_id'>$brand_title</option>
    ";
}

return $return;
```

Comment: You are right, but now the problem is that the function only returns one row of data from table at db!

Comment: @thaeslocrauo I think I know what you mean - I've edited my answer to add the code you need to use.

Comment: Thank u very much <3